# Passing value from dialog form to main form

Tags: c#, forms, dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you pass an object from form1 to form2 and back to form1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887820/how-do-you-pass-an-object-from-form1-to-form2-and-back-to-form1)

I'm used to passing variables between windows forms by simply passing them as a parameter.
Now I have a form that is already open (let's call it `FormMain`), and another form that should act like a dialog (`FormTask`). The user cannot interact with the main form until he has filled in the information on `FormTask`. `FormTask` simply contains a single textbox, and the value of this textbox should be returned to `FormMain`, and kept track of as a variable. `FormTask` requires a parameter `exerciseType`. When `FormTask` opens it checks the value of this parameter and sets the default value of the textbox accordingly. This already works, I'm just kind of clueless on how to return my string value to the already open `MainForm`.
These dialogs only seem to be able to return `DialogResults`, which isn't what I'm after. I'm not too experienced either, and I'd rather avoid fumbling around to make my own custom dialog.

**FormMain:**

```
FormTask formTask = new FormTask(exerciseType);
formOpgaveInvoker.ShowDialog();
```

**FormTask:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string opgave = textBoxOpgave.Text;
    // return string value to MainForm here
}
```

Comment: Since everyone in front of a keyboard has already posted an answer, I won't try to do so myself. But do keep in mind that you should still check the `DialogResult` value returned by the call to `ShowDialog`. You want to allow for the case where the user *canceled* (i.e., closed the form without entering anything at all), and you don't want to treat whatever they entered in the textbox as actual input.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Create public property in FormTask

```
public string Opgave { get {return textBoxOpgave.Text;}}
```

And check it after ShowDialog();

```
FormTask formTask = new FormTask(exerciseType);
formOpgaveInvoer.ShowDialog();
formOpgaveInvoer.Opgave;  // here it is
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I feel pretty stupid right now :P

Comment: `FormTask` will not be disposed like that.  Either call `Dispose()` or (much better yet) use a `using` block.

Comment: Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to add a public property to your form class to return the string.

```
public string opgave
{
    get;
    private set;
}
```

Assign to this property as your dialog closes and then read the property from the code that called `ShowDialog()`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    opgave = textBoxOpgave.Text;
}

...

FormTask formTask = new FormTask(exerciseType);
formOpgaveInvoker.ShowDialog();
DoSomething(formTask.opgave);
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could simply have the property set and return `textBoxOpgave.Text`. Saves a lot of irrelevant lines of code. When you show a form with `ShowDialog`, the controls are guaranteed not to be disposed, precisely so you can read their values. That's why you need to wrap the creation of such forms in a `using` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Forms are just normal classes. This means, you can create properties in them.
So: Create a property and assign the value to it.

Answer (score 1):

Add a property to the `FormTask` for example `String1` like

```
public string String1 {get; set;}
```

Set String1 value in `button1_Click` for example,

You can access that property in MainForm like

```
FormTask formTask = new FormTask(exerciseType);   
formOpgaveInvoer.ShowDialog(); 
string str = formTask.String1;
```