# Textbox won't update when content passed from form 2 to form 1

Tags: c#, winforms

I am referring to the information [from my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969582/how-to-update-textbox-in-form1-from-form2) which tells me in details how to update textbox in form 1 from form 2.

I double checked everything and I still have a problem while updating the textbox. When button clicked it should display content into txtDisplay in MainWindow by using parameter ChangeTextBox. But it doesn't.

Have I missed something here? If not, how can I correct this problem?

**Code with the problem:**

```
        private void btnAddEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Making sure that type is selected.
            if (cmbType.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select entry type!", "Error!", 
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            // Each field must be filled for specified type.
            // Here we are checking if all fields were filled.
            else if ((cmbType.SelectedIndex == 0 && (txtUserName.Text == string.Empty || txtPassword.Text == string.Empty)) ||
                (cmbType.SelectedIndex == 1 && (txtURL.Text == string.Empty || txtPassword.Text == string.Empty)) ||
                (cmbType.SelectedIndex == 2 && (txtSoftwareName.Text == string.Empty || txtSerialCode.Text == string.Empty)))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill all the fields!", "Error!", 
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                int totalEntries = 0;

                mainWindow = new MainWindow();

                if(cmbType.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    addedEntry.Add(new AddPC(cmbType.Text, txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text));
                }
                else if(cmbType.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {
                    addedEntry.Add(new AddWebSite(cmbType.Text, txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text, txtURL.Text));
                }
                else if(cmbType.SelectedIndex == 2)
                {
                    addedEntry.Add(new AddSerialCode(cmbType.Text, txtSoftwareName.Text, txtSerialCode.Text));
                }

                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (var list in addedEntry)
                {
                    if (list is AddPC)
                    {
                        totalEntries++;

                        AddPC tmp = (AddPC)list;

                        stringBuilder.Append(tmp.ToString());
                    }
                    else if (list is AddWebSite)
                    {
                        totalEntries++;

                        AddWebSite tmp = (AddWebSite)list;

                        stringBuilder.Append(tmp.ToString());
                    }
                    else if (list is AddSerialCode)
                    {
                        totalEntries++;

                        AddSerialCode tmp = (AddSerialCode)list;

                        stringBuilder.Append(tmp.ToString());
                    }
                }

                mainWindow.ChangeTextBox = stringBuilder.ToString();

                // The foreach loop works and display because content is showing here.
                MessageBox.Show(stringBuilder.ToString());

                // Clearing all fields.
                ClearFields();
            }
        }
```

Hope for some help.

Regards.

Comment: It's good that you posted your code, but it would help if you described exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: Good point. I have updated my OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you create a new instance of MainWindow, you update the new instance, not the old one. Pass the mainwindow to the secondary window and change this instance, you'll see your changes.

Answer (score 4):

Don't write `mainWindow = new MainWindow();`.
You want the existing `MainWindow`, not a new one.