# How do I invoke a method in a userform from parent form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Learning C#:

I have structure of

```
form1 (splitcontainer)
  userformLeft (button + sub-panel)
    userformDisplay (loaded into panel in userformLeft)
  userformRight
```

I want to execute a method in userformDisplay from form1 (timer in form1).

And the other way around, let's say I have public property form1.mainTimer, can
I call it from userFormDisplay like

```
myLong = this.parent.parent.mainTimer;
```

or similar.

Comment: You will have to pass reference to the form instance when creating the control, then just use that instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar problems of communicating between one form and another... whether attaching to "events" of one, or calling / setting values to/from each other.  Here are a couple links to questions I've answered to in the past that may help understand the relationships to do so.

[Sample 1 with explicit steps to create two forms communicating back/forth to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969582/how-to-update-textbox-in-form1-from-form2/7971828#7971828)

[Sample 2 somewhat similar, but attaching to events between forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887820/how-do-you-pass-an-object-from-form1-to-form2-and-back-to-form1/4887906#4887906)

Answer (score 2):

yes.. you can do this:

```
myLong = ((form1)this.parent.parent).mainTimer;
```