# Passing a Date Value from one Windows From to Another Form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a very complex project and I am very very new to the windows Project.
I have 2 Forms :

- `ViewSchedule.cs`
- `Scheduler.cs` (it is a Dialog Form)

`ViewSchedule.cs` has two dates to be selected from the Calendar. Two dates are selected. 
They are saved in Resp:

```
_fromDate = dtFromDate.DateTime.ToUniversalTime();
_toDate = dtToDate.DateTime.ToUniversalTime();
```

Form 2 ie `Scheduler.cs` is a dialogForm. Here the dates selected in `ViewScheduler` should appear here.

I need help.

Comment: "I need help" isn't a valid question. I re-read your post a few time, and still can't find the question.

Comment: If I have to assume then you are saying that you want to access some data from form1 and show it in form2? Am I correct ?

Comment: Yes,The Form1 date value should appear in the Form2.

Comment: How about keeping a static property that will be set once you set a date and then access it on form 2 ? Will that help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create public properties in the dialog form and set these properties before showing the dialog.

Then onLoad use these property values.

In form2 add these date properties:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public DateTime Date1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date2 { get; set; }

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And from form1 access these as follows:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
   frm2.Date1 = DateTime.Now;
   frm2.Date2 = DateTime.Now;
   frm2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to make sure that these two variables that define the two dates are `public static` so that they can be accessed through the other form. If you'd like to update the other form only if the value is changed. Then, I'd suggest you to have a `Timer` in the second form and a `bool` in the first form that indicates whether the date is changed or not.

**Example**

<sup>**ViewSchedule.cs**</sup>

```
//These values must be static and public so that they'd be accessible through the second form
public static bool DateChanged = false;
public static DateTime _fromDate;
public static DateTime _toDate;

private void SetValues()
{
    _fromDate = dtFromDate.DateTime.ToUniversalTime();
    _toDate = dtToDate.DateTime.ToUniversalTime();
    DateChanged = true; //Set DateChanged to true to indicate that there has been a change made recently
}
```

<sup>**Scheduler.cs**</sup>

```
public Scheduler()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick); //Link the Tick event of timer1 to timer1_Tick
}

DateTime _fromDate; //Set a new variable of name _fromDate which will be used to get the _fromDate value of ViewSchedule.cs
DateTime _toDate; ////Set a new variable of name _toDate which will be used to get the _toDate value of ViewSchedule.cs

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Form1.DateChanged) //Check if a change has been done recently
    {
        Form1.DateChanged = false; //Set the change to false so that the timer won't repeat
        _fromDate = Form1._fromDate; //Set our value of _fromDate from Form1._fromDate
        _toDate = Form1._toDate;//Set our value of _toDate from Form1._toDate
    }
}
```

This will set the values of `Scheduler.cs` to the new values from `ViewSchedule.cs` which I think is what you would like to achieve

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: Seriously? A timer and a dirty flag to poll a global variable? Surely this can be done in a less clunky way.

Comment: @millimoose I've tried to provide the simplest way to do this. Surely, this can be done in many other ways. As far as I believe, this is the simplest way. Please watch your language. Have a great day :)

Comment: @PicrofoEGY It's simple because it's a bad design, and promotes an incredibly bad practice. Using a global variable when you need a chunk  of data accessible in more than one class should be your last resort, not the first thing you reach to.

Comment: @millimoose Sorry about that. Perhaps someone else may answer this. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

You should give `Scheduler` an explicit data source and use events to notify it of changes to the underlying dates. A good idea would be giving the data source its own interface:

```
interface IFromToDateProvider : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    DateTime From { get; }
    DateTime To { get; }
}
```

Then have `ViewSchedule` implement this interface:

```
class ViewSchedule : IFromToDateProvider
{
    DateTime _from;

    public DateTime From
    {
        get { return _from; }
        set
        {
            if (_from == value) return;

            _from = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("From");
        }
    }

    DateTime _to;

    public DateTime To
    {
        get { return _to; }
        set
        {
            if (_to == value) return;
            _to = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("To");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to update the values of from and to using the properties so the event gets fired. Alternately, you can make `From` and `To` computed properties that just grab the value from the `Calendar`s you mention; once again, make sure to fire `OnPropertyChanged` when the underlying calendar values change. If you're using [`MonthCalendar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), you can do this by listening to its [`DateChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.datechanged%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Then, have your `Scheduler` take a `IFromToDateProvider` as a constructor parameter and listen to its `PropertyChanged` event:

```
class Scheduler
{
    readonly IFromToDateProvider _provider;
    public Scheduler(IFromToDateProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
        _provider.PropertyChanged += provider_PropertyChanged;
    }

    void provider_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        // update display with new values in _provider.From and/or 
        // _provider.To in this event handler
    }
}
```

This is assuming that `ViewSchedule` creates a `Scheduler` instance. If it's vice versa, just have `Scheduler` listen to the event after it creates the `ViewSchedule`. If neither, just set it as a property; the essential part is that you end up with `Scheduler` listening to the `PropertyChanged` event of a `ViewSchedule`.

Answer (score 0):

I would not bother with static fields...  This type of question of passing values back/forth between forms has been answered many times...  So to is [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166896/how-do-i-invoke-a-method-in-a-userform-from-parent-form/8168642#8168642) to a previous question I so answered.  It even has a step-by-step on creating two forms and getting values passed back-and-forth via getter/setter and even events.  Hope this helps you out.