# Transferring information from one label in FORM1 to another label in FORM2

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I have a label on Form1 called oldNumber.
When I click a button which loads `Form2`, a `label` called newNumber, will be displayed when form2 loads.

My presumption is for the `label` to display the number from the previous `form` as the `form` loads it must be placed within the `Form2`'s load method. Although I'm not entirely sure how to call the oldNumber in `Form1` to display in the newNumber `Label` on `form2`.

There is similar questions asked to this, but none have managed to help me.

Thanks!

P.s Im new to .NET, and winForms. So question is quite simple i know.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your form2 constructor to receive a string

```
public class Form2:Form
{

    public void Form2(string textFromForm1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.labelOnForm2.Text = textFromForm1;
    }
    ....
}
```

then when you call the Form2 Show/ShowDialog in Form1 instance

```
Form2 frm = new Form2(this.labelOnForm1.Text);
frm.Show();
```

Answer (score -1):

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166896/how-do-i-invoke-a-method-in-a-userform-from-parent-form/8168642#8168642) might help you as there are many similar principles that can be done working with multiple forms that may rely on each other.  It has a few links, even a full sample showing how to work multiple forms / methods / properties, etc

Comment: References to references of references seems like a bad way to answer questions.  If you're going to recycle answers, at least take time to repost the code.

Comment: @DonBoitnott, So noted, but so many questions about how to on formA/formB.  Also, with different options and approaches to giving them a solution was why I pointed to that specific link.

Comment: Then the appropriate course would be to flag as duplicate and vote to close.