# How to update a form with existing information by adding more information from another form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms for submitting a skill update request.

**Form 1:** Is the request form, it contains a datagridview binded by a datatable (not binded to the database)

**Form 2:** The skills form, contains a datagridview control binded to my database, it lists all the skills.

What I want to happen is go be able to click add on form 1, open form 2 select a skill there and then when I click ok, skill details are transferred to form1. I can do it only once. I want to be able to send multiple skills in one request so the previous data **must not be erased**, however it does not happen because Form 2 opens another instance of the form every time.

Form.Activate() and Form.Show and Form.Update does not work. Help?

Open form2 link in form 1 to open form with list of skills.

```
private void AddSkills_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  AddSkill SkillsForm = new AddSkill();
  SkillsForm.Show();
```

From form2 (after selecting which skill the user wants to request)

```
 SkillUpdateRequest SUpdateReq = new SkillUpdateRequest();

 SUpdateReq.FName_txt.Text = fname;
 SUpdateReq.EmpID_Txt.Text = EmpID;
 SUpdateReq.MName_Txt.Text = mname;
 SUpdateReq.LName_Txt.Text = lname;
 SUpdateReq.EmpInitials_Txt.Text = LoggedUser;
 SUpdateReq.Position_Txt.Text = PositionName;

 SUpdateReq.SkillID_Txt.Text = SkillID;
 SUpdateReq.SkillName_Txt.Text = SkillName;
 SUpdateReq.SkillDescription_Txt.Text = SkillDesc;
 SUpdateReq.DateSubmitted_Txt.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();

 SUpdateReq.GetEmpID(EmpID);
 SUpdateReq.Update();
 this.Close();
```

Comment: I think you can add sent data to the data grid view in a new row. So If you update again then your new row is added to datagridview. So you can retrive multiple data.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact data types, lists, data table, whatever you are trying to pass between forms,  these prior posts might help

[One link, multiple form passing back and forth data / control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887820/how-do-you-pass-an-object-from-form1-to-form2-and-back-to-form1/4887906#4887906)

[Another that even samples method calling to go back and forth with data / actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969582/how-to-update-textbox-in-form1-from-form2/7971828#7971828)