# c# getting items of my checkedboxlist in form1 from my form2

Tags: c#

I`m trying to get the items in of my checkedboxlist that is in form1 from my form2.

I did put the propertie of my form1.checkedboxlist MODIFIER to PUBLIC

I can reach the list but i can`t get the items inside. When i used the checkedboxlist.items.count it tells me there is nothing in my list but it is not true

```
string[] list = new string[form1.ckdBoxList.Items.Count];

MessageBox.Show(list.Length.ToString());//In debug it tells me that the lenght is 0

for (int i = 0; i <= list.Length; i++)
{
   list[i] = fenPrincipal.ckdBoxList.Items[i].ToString();
}
```

thank you for your help

Comment: Is form1 still open and visible when you switch to form2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
    string[] list = new string[form1.ckdBoxList.Items.Count];

    MessageBox.Show(form1.ckdBoxList.Items.Count+"");//In debug it tells me that the lenght is 0

    for (int i = 0; i < form1.ckdBoxList.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        list[i] = form1.ckdBoxList.Items[i].ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here' are two links to very similar questions asked and solutions I've offered them.

[Solution option 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969582/how-to-update-textbox-in-form1-from-form2/7971828#7971828)

[Another option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887820/how-do-you-pass-an-object-from-form1-to-form2-and-back-to-form1/4887906#4887906)