# How to get variable from form1 to form2 with { get; set;}?

Tags: c#, winforms

All.

I'm newbie in C#. I know this is very popular question. But I didn't understand. I know there is a mistake, but where? 
For example - first part of code Form1 include private variable test, I need to get the value of this variable in the Form2. Where is the error?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string test = "test this point";
            Form2 dlg = new Form2();
            dlg.test = test;
            dlg.Show();
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public string test { get; set; }

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.Text = test;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you would have to assign it to `Form2 test` property what you have is a independent string which has nothing to do with the property of the the `Form2`. `dlg.test = test;` in `Form1` is needed.

Answer (score 4):

In your Form2 you are using a public property, because it is `public` you can assign it via the object in form1. For example:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 dlg = new Form2();
            dlg.test = "test this point";
            dlg.Show();
        }
```

There are a couple of ways to use this in form 2, if you just want it to set the text property of the label only, this would be the best:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public string test 
        { 
           get { return label1.Text; }
           set { label1.Text = value ;} 
        }

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Within the setter of the property you could also call a function if required.

Comment: Ok. But how to use this variable in the Form2. I changed the code, but nothing happened?!

Answer (score 1):

You are right, this type of question has been asked many times, slightly different versions... Here's some answers I've provided in the past

[This might be closest for what you are looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969582/how-to-update-textbox-in-form1-from-form2/7971828#7971828)

[One answer getting a value via a method calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887820/how-do-you-pass-an-object-from-form1-to-form2-and-back-to-form1/4887906#4887906)

[Another, with step-by-step to create two forms and getting values to/from the other with function or Getter(setter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969582/how-to-update-textbox-in-form1-from-form2/7969676#7969676)

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the string test anywhere within your method. Try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 dlg = new Form2();

    dlg.Test = "test this point";

    dlg.Show();
}
```

See how you're assigning the value to the property `Test` on the Form2 object `dlg`.

Note: I used a captial for the property `Test` since that's the general consensus on style for property names.

Answer (score 0):

test is a property available for `Form2` (better case it to Test) while the `string test` is just scoped for the click event of `Form1`. It has no relation to the property unless you assign it.

```
Form2 dlg = new Form2();
dlg.test = test; // this will assign it
dlg.Show();
```

Now `Form2` property has got the value which will be used to display the same in the `Label`

Comment: Thanks. But how to use this variable in Form2?