# Pass a value to and from two different forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, text, textbox

I have 2 windows forms (Form1 and Form2). (C#)
In Form1 I have a Text and a LinkLabel. When I click the LinkLabel in Form1, Form2 shows. 
In Form2, there is a TextBox and 2 buttons (Ok and Cancel).

What I am trying to do is have the string from the Text in Form1 show up in the TextBox in Form2. The user will then be able to edit the Text in the TextBox, and can Press the Ok button to confirm the changes or press the Cancel button to discard the changes. If the Ok button is pressed, Form2 will close and the Text in Form1 will be changed to whatever was entered into the TextBox from Form2.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the string into Form2's cstor.  Form1 has a reference to the Form2 object because it constructs Form2.  Add a property to Form2.  Set the property and read the property after Form2 closes in Form1.  Conditionally use the value to set the textbox value in Form1 based on the `DialogResult`.

Answer (score 0):

Might be useful from MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288422(v=vs.71).aspx

And for form to show:

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar question to others... Here's some solutions I've offered in the past...

[Option 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514050/how-to-get-variable-from-form1-to-form2-with-get-set/10516884#10516884)

[Option 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887820/how-do-you-pass-an-object-from-form1-to-form2-and-back-to-form1/4887906#4887906)