# How to disable form2 combo boxes based on form1 combo box value?

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, combobox, pass-by-reference

I am trying to disable some of the combo boxes in form 2 based in form 1 selected value.

Lets say 
In Form1 if comboxbox value is 0
Disable certain combo boxes in form 2

What I have done in form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ComboBox combo
    {
        get { return dropdown; } 
    }
```

and in form 2 so far

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Form1 f = new Form1();
  if (f.combo.SelectedIndex == 0)
  {
    comboBox1.Enabled = false;
  }
```

This is not working and I cant sort it out (new to c#)

Comment: In form2 you are again creating new instance of form1 and accessing combo value. it will always have the default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create Form1 at Form with this syntax:

```
  Form1 f = new Form1();
```

You will get new instance of Form1 (or "copy"), not the one thats already open. You need to pass the reference of Form1 to Form2.
Put this code into Form2:

```
private Form1 myParentForm;
public Form2(Form1 parentForm)
{
  myParentForm = parentForm;
}
```

Then you can use Form1 through a variable myParentForm. Like this:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (myParentForm.combo.SelectedIndex == 0)
  {
    comboBox1.Enabled = false;
  }
}
```

In Form1 you have a code something like this:

```
Form2 mySecondForm = new Form2();
```

change that to:

```
Form2 mySecondForm = new Form2(this);
```

Comment: Hi, could you please give an example of using that variable? I didnt get that part. Do I have to use it in form1? or in form2? Where should I put if form1 combobox value = 0 disable form2 comboboxes. I started learning recently so struggling a bit any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: At Form2_Load, change this:
 Form1 f = new Form1();
if (f.combo.SelectedIndex == 0)
  {
    comboBox1.Enabled = false;
  }
to something like this:
  if (parentForm.combo.SelectedIndex == 0)
  {
    comboBox1.Enabled = false;
  }

I Added example to answer

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a prior answer with multiple samples calling one form as parameter to another including one of those as a full step-by-step sample.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514050/how-to-get-variable-from-form1-to-form2-with-get-set/10516884#10516884)

Now, with respect to enable/disable, you can use either property or method approach to tell the "Other" form to enable / disable the status... The samples are just setting / getting values.  If you do a set such as boolean to the one form in question, your setter portion might be something like

```
   private bool enableFromOtherForm;
   public bool EnableFromOtherForm
   { 
      get { return enableFromOtherForm; }
     set { this.controlToChange.IsEnabled = value; }
   }
```