# Using Combo Boxfrom Form1 as main control

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, combobox

I have a main form that contains a combo box full of selections the user can choose from. I then have a couple of other secondary forms that will open within the main form that the user can toggle between that contain different pieces of information related to the combo box on the main form. How can I make it so the combo box on the main form will update the values in other forms, kind of like the IndexChanged function but it will affect all of the other forms?
Here is code for what happens when one of the secondary forms gets open (they all work like this):

```
    private void CrashReports_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage4;
        tabControl1.Visible = true;
        CrashReports CrashReportsTab = new CrashReports(this);
        CrashReportsTab.TopLevel = false;
        panel4.Controls.Add(CrashReportsTab);
        CrashReportsTab.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        CrashReportsTab.TopLevel = false;
        CrashReportsTab.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        CrashReportsTab.Show();
    }
```

In this form, it does some calculations based on what the comboBox in the main form says but I cannot seem to get it to update when the main form changes, only updates the first time the button is clicked based on what the original value was in the main form's combo box. I basically need an excerpt of code that will update my secondary forms immediately when the comboBox in the main form is changed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are all of the other forms of the same type? Are they all `CrashReports` forms?

Comment: They are not all 'CrashReports' forms. They are all different types as they display different types of data.

Comment: See my edit below then. You can either use each of the references and call them out specifically in your `IndexChanged` event or you can always register a handler for your `IndexChanged` event in each of the forms or create a special event that takes in more data and the `IndexChanged` event can loop through your forms and call that special event specifically to get the data around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is always a reference to the other forms somewhere. You just need to make sure that reference is available and access it in the `IndexChanged` event of your `ComboBox`. You can either keep the reference around in a list on your main form or access them through your `panel4.Controls` property.

Think of a messaging structure and what information needs to be passed around. You can always create a Base SubForm that all of the Secondary forms derive from that has some event called `UpdateFromSelectionChange` and that its parameters can take in that information that needs to be passed around. Each form can then handle that event separately and specifically to its own needs.

An example of setting up a handler on a different form.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 myForm2 = new Form2();

        // Do not use this line if you handle looping through the controls
        // in your combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged method.
        comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += myForm2.HandlerForIndexChanges;

        myForm2.Show();
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This handles the selection change.

        foreach (Form2 cont in panel4.Controls.OfType<Form2>())
        {
            cont.SomeOtherWay("Some", "Other", "Way");
        }
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void HandlerForIndexChanges(object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        // I can handle the event change here for my form as well.
    }

    public void SomeOtherWay(string st, string st2, string st3)
    {
        // Access to more data!!!
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I pass the reference to my other forms?

Comment: @AlminPIlica Look at the example I posted. It gives two examples. There are other ways as well to do what you need. You could always keep the `Form2 myForm2` at the class level of `Form1`. Then, you just show it in your button click and it is available to every method in `Form1`.

Comment: @AlminPIlica Check this SO post to see how you can pass the reference of the form around as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441789/how-to-disable-form2-combo-boxes-based-on-form1-combo-box-value?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation.