# Pass data from one form to another

Tags: c#, .net, forms

Today I account a question, In c# winform program.

if there are *Form A* and *Form B*; Form B has a textbox (need to read only)

The Form A code like this:

```
B b = new B("FormB");
b.Show();
```

The FormB code like this:

**Situation1:**

```
public B(string str)
{
   this.textbox1.text = str;

   this.textbox1.Enable = false;
}
```

I deploy the program to customer server, but the `textbox1.text = ""`, have no value, but it works in my local computer.

I try this:

**Situation2:**

```
public B(string str)
{
    this.textbox1.text = str;

    this.textbox1.ReadOnly = true;        
}
```

Then `texbox1.text = "FormB";` it works in my local computer and customer server.

The key and important question is ,why the situation1 can works my local computer not works in customer server?

Can anybody tell this is why?

Comment: where you have initialized you object of formB

Comment: public B(string str)
{
InitializeComponent();
 this.textbox1.text=str;
 this.textbox1.Enable=false;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me see if I understand you correctly, you are asking why the text on the `TextBox` is updated when you use `ReadOnly = true` and **not** `Enabled = false`?

---

If so, I guess it's by design.

From MSDN: [TextBoxBase.ReadOnly Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.readonly.aspx)

> When this property is set to true, the contents of the control cannot
>   be changed by the user at runtime. **With this property set to true, you
>   can still set the value of the Text property in code.** You can use this
>   feature **instead of disabling the control with the Enabled property** to
>   allow the contents to be copied and ToolTips to be shown.

Comment: but ,the situation1 can work fine in my local computer,not work in customer server.how to explain this? because of OS? or runtime?

Comment: Are there different versions of .Net running on your local environment and the customer server env.?

Answer (score 1):

Similar questions have been asked and answered... Here are some samples I've provided

[One Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887820/how-do-you-pass-an-object-from-form1-to-form2-and-back-to-form1/4887906#4887906)

[Another using properties and methods to expose / exchange data -- almost step by step sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969582/how-to-update-textbox-in-form1-from-form2/7969676#7969676)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `InitializeComponent()` in your constructor - the same as the blank constructor.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/initializecomponent

Comment: Calling the base should work too: `public B(string str) : base()`

Comment: of course ,my constructor inlcude InitializeComponent
like this:
public B(string str)
{
InitializeComponent();
 this.textbox1.text=str;
 this.textbox1.Enable=false;
}