# vb.net transfer data from 1 form to another

Tags: vb.net, get, data-transfer

How do i get data from 1 form to another.

example:

in form 1 when user enters something in inputbox("") send the data to form 2/and display it in.

```
Sub form1()
  InputBox("Enter something " & Num, "Read Names")
  form2.show
end sub
```

Comment: what is form 2? did you create it? or is it a form that you can not change?

Comment: no, i create the form, now i have two forms

Comment: Remember to search Stack Overflow for your question - [others may have asked it before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578670/how-to-pass-value-of-a-textbox-from-one-form-to-another-form-in-vb-net).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways you could do this, for example create an instance of form2, and set the property of one of its controls before you show it. If form2 has a label control called Label1:

```
    Dim userName As String = InputBox("Whats your name?")

    Dim infoForm As New Form2
    infoForm.Label1.Text = userName
    infoForm.ShowDialog()
```

As per your comment, you can add the string to the listbox the same way you set the lable:

```
    Dim userName As String = InputBox("Whats your name?")

    Dim infoForm As New Form2
    infoForm.lstItinerary.Items.Add(usersName)
    infoForm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Yes, but how do i display the userName in form2 ?, i added this in form2: Dim userName As String
        lstItinerary.Items.Add(userName)

Comment: Well in my example you have Label1 in form2. I will edit my answer as per your comment

Comment: @user57432 can you please help me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782411/vb-net-if-inputbox-is-greater/13782562