# vb.net if inputbox is greater

Tags: vb.net, inputbox

I'm having trouble checking if input is less then or grater 3 characters.
should i use if statement or while loop?.

and also how to store all the data in listbox after inputbox entered:

```
For Num = 1 To CInt(nudPassengers.Value)
    Dim userName As String
    if userName < 3 then
    InputBox("Whats your name? " & Num)
    Dim infoForm As New frmBooking
    infoForm.lstItinerary.Items.Add(userName)
    end if
Next
```

Comment: where are you checking for the number of characters?

Comment: i didn't do it that's why i need help, but did this: If 3 < CInt(userName) Then

Comment: If `username` contains letters, I doubt CInt will parse something successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Less than 3 characters

```
 If Username.Length < 3 Then

 End If
```

- [String Manipulation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903372%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- [Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hzcd8ze0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: @ikslake: Above code is C#. VB.NET does not need brackets. Should be `If input.Length < 3 Then`.

Comment: You need to go and learn more - you should have replaced `input` with your own variable name e.g. `Username`

Comment: @codingbiz i'm learning, but i'm still a beginner that's why i need help, btw i'm coding vb not c++,:facepalm, useless

Comment: This is VB.Net. And C# is not C++, and it's not useless.

Comment: the answaer above is right, but what if i have it decalre like this: Dim userName As String 
InputBox("Whats your name? ")