# How can I assign a value of a variable using textbox from another form?

Tags: vb.net

This is my code

form1:

```
public sometext as string
```

form2:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click  
        textbox1.text = form1.sometext  
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In form 1:

```
Dim Obj as New Form2
Obj.Str = 'some variable in form 1'
Obj.Show
Me.Hide
```

In form 2:

```
Public Property Str as String
Textbox1.text = Str
```

And for more information you could check this link: [How to pass value of a textbox from one form to another form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578670/how-to-pass-value-of-a-textbox-from-one-form-to-another-form)