# How to use a variable of Form2 in Form1, WinForms C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, scope

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2013 which contains two Forms. I want when a button pressing in Form2, the variable `flag_fb` is updated and I use its value in Form1. Is there any way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "variable `flag_fb`"? Is it a member of Form1?

Comment: Show us you code. What did you try?

Comment: yes, flag_fb is a member of Form1. But it does not matter. I want to update a variable such as flag_fb when pressing a button in Form2 and use its updated value in Form1.

Comment: when it is raining a flag in form1 is set. when it is set Form2 opens to alarm the user weather status. I want by pressing a button in Form2 flag_fb chenge to inform me user knows the weather status.

Comment: You could use a public static variable/property or use a separate application wide static class entirely to hold those variables,and then update the value of from anywhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you pass an object from form1 to form2 and back to form1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887820/how-do-you-pass-an-object-from-form1-to-form2-and-back-to-form1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method1 :** using parameterized constructor to pass the variables between forms

create a parameterized constructor for `Form1` and call the Form1 parameterized constructor from Form2 :

```
//form1 code

bool flag_fb =false;
public Form(bool flag_fb)
{
  this.flag_fb = flag_fb;
}
```

call the `Form1` parameterized constructor from `Form2` as below:

```
//form2 code

Form1 form1=new Form1(flag_fb);
from1.Show();
```

**Method2 :** create your variable `flag_fb` as `public static` variable in `Form2` so that it willbe accessible from `Form1` aswell.

```
//Form2 code

public static bool flag_fb = true;
```

To access the `flag_fb variable` from `Form1` just use className as below:

```
//Form1 code

bool form2flagValue = Form2.flag_fb ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should also work.

```
// Open form2 from form1
using (Form2 form2 = new Form2())          
{
 if (form2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
 {

   m_myVal = form2.flag_fb;

 }

}
```

You should make sure `flag_fb` is public member variable of `Form2`, and
also make sure it is set to desired value when user clicks OK for instance.