# How to pass data from childform to parentform

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two forms ,Form1 and Form2.

Form1 - Parent
Form2 - Child

Form1 Contains the following,

Textbox - it loads the file path,
Datagridview - it loads the file with its data,
ButtonNext -when button cliked it opens Form2,

Form2 Contains the following,

BrowseButton - it broswe for the file from the directory
Textbox - it then shows the path
ButtonFinish - it will tabes you back to Form1

*Now i want to access datagridview from Form1(Parent) from Form2(child). Now i can broswe the file on Form2 and when i click finish i can see my file path on Form1(parent) from the textbox but with no databeing loaded.

How can i load the data on Form1 into the datagridview ?

this is my code so far..

Form2.

```
    public frmInputFile(frmMain_Page _frmMain)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this._frmMain = _frmMain;
    }

private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     BrowseFile();
}

 private void btnFinish_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {

        _frmMain.SetFilepath(txtInputfile.Text);
        _grid.Rows.Clear();          //cant get the grid from form1
        string PathSelection = "";
        if (txtInputfile.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            PathSelection = txtInputfile.Text;
        }
        oDataSet = new DataSet();
        XmlReadMode omode = oDataSet.ReadXml(PathSelection);

        for (int i = 0; i < oDataSet.Tables[2].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string comment = oDataSet.Tables["data"].Rows[i][2].ToString();
            string font = Between(comment, "[Font]", "[/Font]");
            string datestamp = Between(comment, "[DateStamp]", "[/DateStamp]");
            string commentVal = Between(comment, "[Comment]", "[/Comment]");
            string[] row = new string[] { oDataSet.Tables["data"].Rows[i][0].ToString(), oDataSet.Tables["data"].Rows[i][1].ToString(), font, datestamp, commentVal };
            _grid.Rows.Add(row);
        }
       this.Hide();
        Program._MainPage.Show();
```

Form1

```
    private void btnLoadfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmInputFile frmInput = new frmInputFile(this);
        frmInput.Show();

    }
    public void SetFilepath(string Filepath)
    {
        txtInputfile.Text = Filepath;
    }
    //I dont know how i can handle the gridview here
    public void Loadgrid(string LoadGrid)
    {
        Gridview_Input.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you pass an object from form1 to form2 and back to form1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887820/how-do-you-pass-an-object-from-form1-to-form2-and-back-to-form1)

Comment: It looks duplicate but with different question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first. Please avoid duplicate posts.

What is the variable _grid doing here ?? Your way of passing data from one form to the other looks very strange. Nevertheless, I tried to simulate your problem and I am able to add the rows in Form1 from From2. The code listing is given below. Just a thing to note,I have added four columns in to my DataGridView in the designer. In your case you might want to add the columns as well programmatically.

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(Form1 frm1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form1Prop = frm1;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1Prop.SetFilepath("HIHI");

        Form1Prop.DataGridPropGrid.Rows.Add("HIH", "KI", "LO", "PO");
    }

    public Form1 Form1Prop { get; set; }
}




 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this);
        frm2.Show();
    }

    public void SetFilepath(string filepath)
    {
        textBox1.Text = filepath;
    }

    public DataGridView DataGridPropGrid
    {
        get
        {
            return dataGridView1;
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Yoh!...you saved my life.I have being stuck with this for days.

Thanks!