# Reference another class member

Tags: c#, reference, ref

I have three classes (`Data`, `First`, `Second` ).

I'm creating member of `Data` in `First` and try to pass it to `Second` with the following:

```
public class First
{
    public Data DataMember;
    Second SecondMember;

    void First_Function()
    {
        SecondMember.Second_Function(ref DataMember);
    }
}

public class Second
{    
    Data DataMember;

    public void Second_Function(ref Data data)
    {

    }    
}
```

Is there a way to access the `First.Data` member in `Second.Data` member?

Using `ref` in the `Second.Second_Function()` allows me to access the member of the `First` but only inside the `Second_Function()`.

I want another function in `Second` to access it, that has a different "call back time" as the `Second_Function()`.

Edit :

My question in not about what is the difference between the reference and value type .

if I use ref keyword for a int variable , that mean if I replace it with another value it will effect the original .

in class when I have two variable reference to the same instance if I edit one of them I effect the other , that's because they reference to the same thing ,I want to know if there is a way in C# to replace one of the variable ,and make the other variable change with it .

Comment: Do you *only* want the classes to share this `Data` i.e. avoid making a public property?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you pass an object from form1 to form2 and back to form1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887820/how-do-you-pass-an-object-from-form1-to-form2-and-back-to-form1)

Comment: *" I want another function in the Second class to access it"* - then second class need an instance of its *parent* (as member, e.g. `private` field). Btw, you have `NullReferenceException` right now.

Comment: yeah I didn't write the data class , its just to explain the idea

Comment: Why dont you write ``this.DataMember = data;`` in your ``Second_Function()``?

Comment: Rand does this mean that DataMember in the second class well Point the same DataMember in the First class ?

Comment: @Honey since you used ``ref``, yes it does

Comment: @RandRandom: Assuming `Data` is a class, that's got nothing to do with using `ref`.

Comment: @JonSkeet - assuming he has the mentioned line in place, if I am not mistaken, if he would say ``instanceOfFirst.DataMember = new Data();`` the ``Second.DataMember`` would change the instance aswell or?

Comment: @RandRandom: No, that wouldn't change `Second.DataMember` at all. The `DataMember` field is just a regular field - it doesn't matter whether it was initialized with a value taken from a `ref` parameter.

Comment: @JonSkeet - thought he would keep the reference "intact", than sorry for spreading nonsense

Comment: @JonSkeet - just out of curiosity would there be a way to do that?

Comment: @RandRandom: This is why it's important to distinguish between *a reference* and when a variable is *passed by reference*. But no, you can't create a "ref field". (There's a lot more you can do with ref now than before, and more coming in C# 7.2, but not that as far as I'm aware.)

Comment: @Honey replace without effecting the main object? if so, you can use Cloning

Answer (score 4):

> There are two kinds of types in C#: reference types and value types.
>   Variables of reference types store references to their data (objects),
>   while variables of value types directly contain their data. With
>   reference types, two variables can reference the same object;
>   therefore, operations on one variable can affect the object referenced
>   by the other variable. With value types, each variable has its own
>   copy of the data, and it is not possible for operations on one
>   variable to affect the other (except in the case of ref and out
>   parameter variables, for more details see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)

Here an example:

**Explanation**

1. Pass your data object to the class `First`, `Second` as parameter in the constructor
2. Any updates happens on the data object inside `First` or `Second` will be reflected on the data object outside these classes because it is `reference type`

   public class Data{
       public Data(int value)
       {
           this.Value = value;
       }
       public int Value{get;set;}
   }

   public class First{
       private Data m_data;
       public First(Data data)
       {
           m_data = data;
       }
       public void Add(int value)
       {
           if(m_data!=null)
               m_data.Value+=value;
       }
   }

   public class Second{
       private Data m_data;
       public Second(Data data)
       {
           m_data = data;
       }
       public void Multiply(int value)
       {
           if(m_data!=null)
               m_data.Value*=value;
       }
   }

now let us setup this scenario

```
var data = new Data(10);
var first = new First(data);
var second = new Second(data);          
second.Multiply(5);         
first.Add(10);
```

What do you expect the value inside the class data? 10? you are wrong, the value is 60

Here a working [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FSeD6r)

Hope this will help you

Comment: "In c# all data are referenced" - that's a bad start. it's important to understand the difference between reference types and value types, and what `ref` does. (Assuming the reader would expect the wrong result isn't great either.)

Comment: I meant by this phrase what I included in my example, you might put `a = b.clone()`, here you are not referencing it, sorry my english

Comment: Right, so there are plenty of subtleties. Several ways to change data: a) changing a reference type field value to refer to a different object; b) changing a value type field value to a different value; c) changing a value within the object a reference type field value refers to; d) mutating a value type stored in a field. All the more reason to avoid massive blanket statements such as  
"In c# all data are referenced". That doesn't help anyone IMO.

Comment: Thank your for the great comment, I updated my answer and hope now it will be more clear for the reader and forgive my mistake :P